# Smart Folders: What is the difference between "This Mac" and "All My Files"?

Tags: smart-folders

What is the difference between "This Mac" and "All My Files"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"All My Files" will only find files that match the search criterion and not, for example, folders or emails even though they also match it.   'This Mac' finds everything that matches the search no matter what it is - file, folder or email. You can test this by creating a file and a folder of the same unique name and searching in "This Mac' and 'All My Files" - the 'All My Files" will not find the folder.

Answer (score 1):

All my files could contain files from mounted or networked drives.

Comment: And "Shared" then means *just* networked drives? So you can say "All My Files" = "This Mac" + "Shared" + mounted-dirs, where all sets on the right site are disjunct? Can you link to some documentation where it clearly says that?